# Get Thumbnail ID Wordpress wp_generate_attachment_metadata

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for someone who can explain me how can I get the thumbnail ID generated by the function "wp_generate_attachment_metadata". 
And I really don't want to work with plugins
I'll use it to modify the thumbnail of a custom_post_type.

Thank you !

Comment: I just resolved some problems regarding this issue , can you better explain the scenario ? do you have a POST id at the time when you want to generate it ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally it would be

```
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
```

Of course , for that you have to have the ID of the post .
If you do not , please specify the exact scenario in details.

Comment: I writing the possibilty to add custom_post_type from the front-end. It's working. Now I want make it better by adding the possibility to upload the thumbnail. Here is what i want to do [link](http://pastie.org/4123364)

Comment: well, in that case the above should work .your first function on the insert_attachment() returns the  post ID .

Comment: It still not working. `$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filedest, $ajout );
    require_once( ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php' );
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filedest );
    $post_id = wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $attach_id );
    update_post_meta( $ajout, '_thumbnail_id', $post_thumbnail_id );`

Comment: What is echo $attach_id before $post_thumbnail_id ? and what is $post_id ?

Comment: I really don't understand, I can't get back the thumb_id. I'm doing a print of get_post_meta from _wp_attacment_metadata and I have no ID. I'm looking in Php my admin, and I never see any Id register only a table with the path to the file (_wp_attached_file) and a link to the other dimensions but no Id in ther (_wp_attachment_metadata)

Comment: what do you mean 'echo are right, they are the ID's from phpMyAdmin' - I asked what is the result of the echo.. and get post meta will give you array ..

Comment: Yes it gives me an array, i've print_r it to see what's in it.

Comment: And when I'm saying echo are right, its because i've done echo $attach_id; and it give the right id from PhpMyAdmin (Sorry my english is really bad)

Comment: can you put the array , the echo results and the print_r results ? it is nice that you know them, but if you do not show it , we can not troubleshoot..

Comment: Here is what I do in php : [link](http://pastie.org/4125155) and here is my i've got back : [link](http://pastie.org/4125157)

Comment: 2 things - first , I asked you to show me also `echo $attach_id` . second - the `$post_thumbnail_id = `get_post_thumbnail_id($attach_id);` works on POST id not attach_id , so ypu need to try `get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id)`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see $attach_id's echo wasn't on the pastie. So here is the php code [PhpCode](http://pastie.org/4125532) and here is what a I have in result [result](http://pastie.org/4125539)

Comment: listen , it seems that we can not understand eachother , i do not know what is the variable `$ajout` - please try what i said in the other comment and use 'get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id)' - otherwise, I have no Idea how to continue and try to help --

Comment: Thank you, $ajout is just this : `$ajout = wp_insert_post($new_cafe,true);`

Comment: try to drop the ' $post_id = ` `$post_id = from wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );` - after that , if this does not work, I will need all your code , because you are giving unrelated fragments all the time ..

Comment: Thank you for all your answers ! I'm doing it in other way (no good but work) I'll come back on it in a few days